# Virtual Machines List from PowerShell vs PowerShell ISE and PowerGUI

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, virtual-machines, windows

I am confused to why I have different information based on where I try to retrieve it from. I have 3 Windows 2012 servers (G0, G1, and G2) running Hyper-V. The following situation is captured from one server which I use to run scripts and control the others.

What I'm trying to do is to get a list of the virtual machines in existence on these 3 machines:

**Using `PowerGUI` and `PowerShell ISE`:**

```
PS > Get-VMHost | select name

Name                                                                                               
----                                                                                               
G0.nothing.com                                                                       
G2.nothing.com                                                                           
G1.nothing.com                                                                           


PS > Get-VMHost | Get-VM | select name

Name                                                                                               
----                                                                                               
VM1628856-4                                                                                        
VM1628856-2                                                                                        
VM1628856-6                                                                                        
VM1628856-3                                                                                        
VM1628856-1                                                                                        
VM1628856-5
```

**Using `PowerShell`:**

```
PS > Get-VMHost | select name

Name
----
G0


PS > Get-VM

Name         State       CPUUsage(%) MemoryAssigned(M) Uptime   Status
----         -----       ----------- ----------------- ------   ------
VM1107610-1  OffCritical 0           0                 00:00:00 Cannot connect to virtual machine configuration storage
VM1390728-1  OffCritical 0           0                 00:00:00 Cannot connect to virtual machine configuration storage
VM1393540-1  OffCritical 0           0                 00:00:00 Cannot connect to virtual machine configuration storage
VM1393540-10 OffCritical 0           0                 00:00:00 Cannot connect to virtual machine configuration storage
VM1393540-2  OffCritical 0           0                 00:00:00 Cannot connect to virtual machine configuration storage
VM1393540-3  OffCritical 0           0                 00:00:00 Cannot connect to virtual machine configuration storage
VM1393540-4  OffCritical 0           0                 00:00:00 Cannot connect to virtual machine configuration storage
VM1393540-5  OffCritical 0           0                 00:00:00 Cannot connect to virtual machine configuration storage
VM1393540-6  OffCritical 0           0                 00:00:00 Cannot connect to virtual machine configuration storage
VM1393540-7  OffCritical 0           0                 00:00:00 Cannot connect to virtual machine configuration storage
VM1393540-8  OffCritical 0           0                 00:00:00 Cannot connect to virtual machine configuration storage
VM1393540-9  OffCritical 0           0                 00:00:00 Cannot connect to virtual machine configuration storage
VM1833022-1  OffCritical 0           0                 00:00:00 Cannot connect to virtual machine configuration storage
```

My main concern is that I don't have reliable information from the 3 tools. The `Hyper-V Manager` application shows the same list as the `PowerShell` does. But if I run my scripts from the other two tools, which is what I mostly do, I don't have the same information available, therefore I can't manipulate the same VMs.

I've also noticed that the `Virtual Machine Manager` shows the same list of VMs as the first two tools, PowerGUI and PowerShell ISE.

Which information is valid? And how can I retrieve the correct list of VMs?

### EDIT 1

The `$env:psmodulepath` value:

```
PS > $env:psmodulepath
C:\Users\administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012\Virtual Machine Manager\bin\Configuration Providers\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012\Virtual Machine Manager\bin\psModules\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\QLogic Corporation\QInstaller\Modules
```

### EDIT 2

`PowerShell` is using this `Hyper-V` module: 
*C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell\v4.0_6.3.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.dll*

And `PowerGUI` is using this one: 
*C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Hyper-V\Hyper-V.psd1*

If I try to load the module used by `PowerShell` onto `PowerGUI` I still get the same different results.

How can I receive the correct information listed under `Hyper-V` using `PowerGUI` or `PowerShell ISE`?

Comment: This also may be relevent: http://blogs.technet.com/b/jeevanbisht/archive/2012/02/12/scvmm-2008-r2-get-vmhost-sometimes-does-not-returning-full-list-of-vms.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I would bet you are using two different Hyper-V PowerShell modules:

```
NAME
  Get-VMHost

SYNOPSIS
  Lists Hyper-V servers registered with Active Directory.
```

this is the Get-VMhost cmdlet from [pshyperv.codeplex.com](http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/), it list multiple Hyper-V hosts, in your case 3

```
NAME
  Get-VMHost

SYNOPSIS
 Gets a Hyper-V host.
```

This is the Get-VMhost cmdlet that comes with Hyper-V 3 on Server 2012+, it simply lists information about one specific host, it never lists multiple hosts.

If both modules are loaded, it seems ISE picks a different preference over PoweShell with these modules.

If you have the built-on cmdlets in 2012 I would not use the third-party cmdlets, it is just confusing, it certainly confused you.

What's the value of your `$env:psmodulepath` ?

Comment: `PS > $env:psmodulepath
C:\Users\administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012\Virtual Machine Manager\bin\Configuration Providers\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012\Virtual Machine Manager\bin\psModules\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\QLogic Corporation\QInstaller\Modules`

Comment: @slybloty - So do you have the codeplex HyperV module installed? If not, it seems System Center also brings some Hyper-V related modules. Compare the command `Get-Module | select Name,Path` in PowerShell and ise, it lists all loaded modules and you should look for any Hyper-V related modules. You can use `Remove-Module` to unload a module from the current session to avoid the conflict in cmdlet names.

Comment: I have updated the question with information about the Hyper-V modules used.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Peter is on the right track. Have you tried:

1. Removing the Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.dll module from PS console with Remove-Module cmdlet
2. Import the module referenced in PowerGUI?

Use this command to verify the command is being used from the correct module.

```
Get-Module (get-command Get-VMHost).ModuleName | select Name, Path
```

Alternatively use the fully qualified name after verifying the module in imported.

```
Hyper-V\Get-VMHost "hyperv01svr"
```

Comment: I have awarded the bounty to this answer because it led me to the best way (as of now) to address this issue I have. I still don't know what causes the discrepancy between the 2 platforms and how to eliminate it, but at least I am blocked by it.

Answer (score -1):

The Host has the ability to set a [default formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for different types, which will be used when you call the select-object cmdlet and send the results to out-default. It may also be that in this case the cmdlet is changing the output based on the value of $host.name.

If you want the same output you can try passing it through format-list or format-table instead of select. In some cases you may also need to pass it to out-string to "lock" the output, as some hosts do not support the format cmdlets (especially when run as a script or in non-interactive mode).

If you really want to inspect the output it would be best to save it to a variable using `... |  Set-Variable testing` or `$testing = ...` and then use `$testing | Get-Member` to see if the same object was returned. In some cases you may need to add the -Force flag to include the [PSObject ATS and ETS methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2011/11/22/psobject-and-the-adapted-and-extended-type-systems-ats-and-ets.aspx?Redirected=true) that are used to wrap the base type.

Examples:

```
Get-VMHost | ft Name | Out-String
Get-VM | Set-Variable VMs
$VMs | Select -First 1 | Get-Member
$VMs | Select -First 1 | GM -Force
```

I don't have access to a HyperV server for testing, but the above is what I usually use to test odd behavior between different hosts.

Comment: My problem is not output formatting. It's the fact that I get different information from the different places. Check the number of hosts and the number and names of the VMs. Completely different. That's the problem I want fix.

Comment: See http://blogs.technet.com/b/jeevanbisht/archive/2012/02/12/scvmm-2008-r2-get-vmhost-sometimes-does-not-returning-full-list-of-vms.aspx

Comment: That blog does not address the reason why there are 2 different lists of VMs and the fact that I don't know which is accurate and how to retrieve the correct one.