# Hyper-V VMs that are turned on are missing in Hyper-V Manager

Tags: hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V VM that is currently on and running but I cannot see it in Hyper-V Manager. If I configure a virtual machine that does appear, I can see in the drop box, in the upper left corner, that I can select it and reconfigure it but it does not appear in the Hyper-V Manager.

Is there a way to "reimport" it like VMWare's solutions or some kind of PowerShell command?

Comment: I have encountered a similar issue too where different lists of VMs appear in different places, like PowerShell vs Hyper-V vs VMM. It seems to be some sort of a discrepancy in the Windows modules and the way they store the data. Check out [this posting](http://serverfault.com/q/570578/127389).

Comment: Isnt that list for multiple hosts? I only have ONE Hyper-V host. I have never touched Hyper-V thru PowerShell so...

Comment: Any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyper-V has autosolved it itself.

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same issue,
I solved it by selecting the broken vm via the dropdown and then I changed one setting (in my case I disabled the snapshot function)

After that my vm is available again.

Comment: The _question_ was "[i]s there a way to "reimport" it like VMWare's solutions or some kind of PowerShell command?" How is this the answer to that question? How did you determine that it is "the same issue?" OP's "accepted" answer says _nothing_ about doing _anything_ with a "snapshot function."

Comment: And my answer is "There is no need to do such a thing in the described case, because the VM is still registered but not shown, so just edit one setting like for example change the snapshot function and then everything is working like it should again."